# Upgrade Selenium from version 20.2.1 to 20.3.3 in PowerShell

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, upgrade

I'm using Selenium to do a WhatsApp bot. However, the Selenium when I use `pip install selenium`says that is recommendable that I upgrade the selenium version. If is recommendable and not obrigatory, I didn't do, but the script didn't run because of this.

Here is what appears when i use `pip install selenium`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\gabri\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from selenium) (1.26.2)
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.1; however, version 20.3.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So what I can do to fix this? I didn't get the instuctions that the powershell gave to me.

Comment: It means you can upgrade pip to newer version, not selenium.

Comment: Your selemium package is up to date.
`C:\Users\......\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip`
Use the command it gave you to upgrade pip.

Answer (score 0):

```
'C:\Users\gabri\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

even solution is there in the error itself . The warning means there is new version of pip (the package manager and not the package you are trying to install) . Just run above command to update pip .